# React - using inline important styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React in a chrome extension and I need to insert elements into the page via the content script. The extension may insert these elements into any page in which it's loaded on (kind of like Last Pass would) so I need to override any existing styling that might target general elements.

For the most part i've managed to get around this via using iframes as css in iframes can't be modified but I need to give styling to the iFrames and one or two parent containers in order for them to display properly.

As i've just learnt you unfortunately can't use the !important feature with inline React CSS. I can maybe understand why this is but for things live Chrome Extensions that use content scripts I need to be able to use important tags...

I've been looking for a work around and managed to find this:

[react-with-important-style](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-with-important-style)

But whenever the component renders it doesn't look very smooth at all so looking for another option.

Can anyone recommend a good workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I can not say it is a good workaround because it uses refs (inline), but it will do the trick. You can simply insert this below snippet as an inline property
as mentioned in this [post](https://www.crowdsync.io/blog/2018/03/22/how-to-important-inline-styles-in-react/)

```
ref={(el) => {
      if (el) {
        el.style.setProperty('background-color', color, 'important');
      }
    }
}
```

Moreover, there is a hack for earlier versions of ReactJS, that [zpao](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1881#issuecomment-127769813) posted.
i.e.

```
style = {
  color: 'red',
  backgroundColor: {
    value: 'blue',
    important: 'true'
  }
}
```

Another approach is this:

```
<style>{"\
i{\
float:none !important;\
}\
"}</style>
```

Use above code in your JSX as shown below:

```
 let activityStats = <table className="table" id="act-stats-user">
        <style>{"\
            i{\
              float:none !important;\
            }\
          "}</style>
        <tbody>
          ...
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

> If nothing works, then the perfect solution to this problem is to
> create a custom.css file, import it and write your CSS there with
> !important (if it`s that important)

---

P.S: try to avoid using `!important` all the time, as it is considered to be a bad practice among the developers but occasionally it`s legal I think :).